# jQuery when().done() on multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with progressbar. 
I want to progressbar changed after loading each next function.
This is my code:

```
var tick=1;
var count=10; 
function example(){
  $('#progress div').css('width',(tick*count)+'%');
  tick++;
}
$.when($.getJSON("data1.json",function(_a){data1=_a;})).done(function(){
  example();
  $.when(someLoadFunction).done(function(){
    example();
    $.when(someLoadFunction2).done(function(){
      example();
      //7 more...
    });
  });
});
```

how to simplify the script, so that it can be easily expanded in the future.

Comment: First simplification is to not use `$.when` there, because anyway you are pssing to it only one promise each time So e.g: `$.when(someLoadFunction).done(function(){...});` is the same as `someLoadFunction().done(function(){...});`. Now could your run all these raquests in paralell, not one after the other?

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of functions to call, then loop through those functions. Not a jQuery user, so there may be more efficient ways of doing this, but at least this is reasonably maintainable. Or as @A. Wolff suggests... Use chaining.

N.B. If you want to use a different callback per function, pass an object literal into function with function/callback instead (no need for callback parameter in this case).

```
$.when($.getJSON("data1.json", function(_a) {
  data1 = _a;
})).done(function() {
  var functionArr = []; //array of functions
  loopWhen(functionArr, example());
});


function loopWhen(functionArr, callback) {
   (var i = 0; i < functionArr.length; i++) {
     $.when(functionArr[i]).done() {
       callback();
     };
   };
 };
```

Comment: Quite okay @A.Wolff :-) If I'm honest, I do not like this solution.... It's too messy for my liking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.queue()`, `.promise()`, `.then()`. Store functions in an array, call next function in array in sequential order when current function promise is resolved. Return a jQuery promise object from and use `example` as a function parameter to `.then()`

```js
var tick = 0;
var count = 10;
var url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/"
          + "guest271314/23e61e522a14d45a35e1/"
          + "raw/a5ac6cffdc1ffab39f9db425844721b528751654/a.json";
// handle errors
function err(e) {
  console.log(e)
}

function example(data) {
  // do stuff
  console.log(data);
  $("#result").append(data + "<br><br>");
  // return `.promise()`
  return $("#progress div")
         .css("width", (++tick * count) + "%")
         .promise()
}

function progress(fn, next) {
  return fn().then(example).then(next).fail(err)
}
// e.g., `someLoadFunction`, `someLoadFunction2`..
function someFunction() {
  return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    return dfd.resolve(tick)
  })
}
// e.g., `$.getJSON()`, `someLoadFunction`, `someLoadFunction2`..
var arr = [
  function() {return $.getJSON(url)}
  , someFunction, someFunction, someFunction // `someLoadFunction2`..
  , someFunction, someFunction, someFunction // `someLoadFunction5`..
  , someFunction, someFunction, someFunction // `someLoadFunction8`..
];

$({}).queue("progress", $.map(arr, function(deferred) {
  return $.proxy(progress, null, deferred)
})).dequeue("progress").promise("progress")
.then(function() {console.log("complete")});
```

```css
#progress div {
  background: blue;
  width: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progress">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```